# Button Default Styling on refresh

Tags: css

Not sure why I am getting this error, but when I refresh the page on chrome (it seems to work fine on Firefox and IE) I can see the default styling of my button. Now, I did some search and most of the answers indicate that there is something wrong with my HTML. I used the W3 validator and it says that an a tag should not be inside a button tag. I removed the a tag, just to see if it works and cleaned my cache and cookies, but I still get the error... here is a link to my [gh-pages](http://lucky500.github.io/styleChallenge/)

[image]

```css
/* Buttons */

.button {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 18px;
}

#applyButton {
 width: 150px;
 height: 48px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 2%;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 background: rgba(12, 12, 12, .3);
 margin-top: 25px;
}

#applyButton a {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, serif;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#applyButton:hover {
 background: #a0ce4e;
 border: 1px solid #a0ce4e;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#applyButton:active {
 border: none;
}
```

```html
   <section id="hero" class="panel">
    <section class="inner-wrapper">
     <h1>Find Your Dream Home</h1>
     <h2>Don't break the bank. Let us help you get the home you love</h2>
     <section class="heroPercentage">
      <h3>2.99%</h3>
      <p>First 6 months</p>
     </section>
        <section>
          <button id='applyButton'>Apply Now</button>
        </section>       
    </section>
   </section>
```

Comment: It's ok for me in chrome and FF also. I do not see any invalid tag in your HTML.

Comment: Do you mean the FOUC on refresh? That's simply caused by the background image being 4MB in size. Try trimming it down. Even saving in a lower quality JPEG will help.

Comment: I mean the apply now button ... but I am going to try to reduce the image. That might do it.

Comment: I actually removed the bg image, and I am still having the issue.

Comment: Your site working smoothly in chrome and fire but in IE it's total loss, actually you shouldn't focus on IE because it's waste of time, this is just an opinion IE is just a crap.

Comment: The `transition` property of `#applyButton` might be the problem here. Try changing it to `transition: background 0.5s,  border 0.5s;`.

Comment: Yes Michael, the transition was the problem. Although I made the changes that you suggested, I simply moved the transition to the :hover state and it fixed. Thanks!